# Which is better to use, Armory or MultiBit and why?

Tags: multibit, armory

Armory slows my system WAY down and I am confused on the difference really. I understand the securities involved.

Also, If I stick with Armory, Can I move it to a different computer and access it there instead of my main one?

Comment: Could you clarify your question please? A question asking for "better" is difficult to answer. What features are you looking for, specifically?

Comment: With Armory, like most wallets, you can backup your wallet and then import or restore it on another computer.